# sqlite syntax error with simple task on apache airflow-2.0

Tags: python, airflow

i have just installed apache airflow according to the following steps:

1. `pip install "apache-airflow[celery, crypto, postgres, mysql, rabbitmq, redis]"  --constraint constraints-3.7.txt`
2. `airflow db init`
3. `mkdir airflow/dags`
4. Set to False the `load_examples` variables at airflow.cfg file.
5. Created a user.

I'm using a Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS VM and a virtual enviroment with Python 3.7.8 installed.

```
~$ sqlite3 --version 
3.11.0
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
```

My dag inside the dags folder is the following:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

def print_hello():
        sleep(5)
        return 'Hello World'

with DAG('hello_world_dag', description='First DAG', schedule_interval='*/10 * * * *', start_date=datetime(2018, 11, 1), catchup=False) as dag:
        dummy_task      = DummyOperator(task_id='dummy_task', retries=3)
        python_task     = PythonOperator(task_id='python_task', python_callable=print_hello)

        dummy_task >> python_task
```

At the execution dummy task runs perfectly, otherwise, python task throws this error:

```
[2020-12-31 12:23:27,493] {taskinstance.py:1396} ERROR - (sqlite3.OperationalError) near ",": syntax error
[SQL: DELETE FROM rendered_task_instance_fields WHERE rendered_task_instance_fields.dag_id = ? AND rendered_task_instance_fields.task_id = ? AND (rendered_task_instance_fields.dag_id, rendered_task_instance_fields.task_id, rendered_task_instance_fields.execution_date) NOT IN (SELECT rendered_task_instance_fields.dag_id, rendered_task_instance_fields.task_id, rendered_task_instance_fields.execution_date 
FROM rendered_task_instance_fields 
WHERE rendered_task_instance_fields.dag_id = ? AND rendered_task_instance_fields.task_id = ? ORDER BY rendered_task_instance_fields.execution_date DESC
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?)]
[parameters: ('hello_world_dag', 'python_task', 'hello_world_dag', 'python_task', 30, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/home/vagrant/.sandbox/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ",": syntax error
```

Comment: Try update sqlite3

Comment: i tried `sudo pip install --upgrade pysqlite` but got: _pysqlite is not supported on Python 3. When using Python 3, use the sqlite3 module from the standard library._ as result

Comment: Try these procedure to update sqlite3 : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_installation.htm

Comment: updated to 3.34.0 and still getting the same error, after upgrade i also tried to do apache airflow installation again but doesn't solve the error

Comment: Hello, I found [this](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/13397) github issue which is related to your issue. Most likely you'll have to upgrade the version of sqlite3 you're using. If you're using Linux, that means that you'll have to upgrade your OS version, for example from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the sqlite version,

Databases:"  * PostgreSQL:  9.6, 10, 11, 12, 13

- MySQL: 5.7, 8
- SQLite: 3.15.0+

ou have 3.11.0

just update (:

you can see it here: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13496/commits/ecd269c776220b67d4cf8f98ca672d77169cb50b